# How to restrict docker group users ability to attach running docker containers which were started by another group user?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, containers, root

I have some user (A, B, ...) in the docker group, basically, each user can start a container from an image but the problem occurs when user A start a container in background (with -d flag). At this time, user B can attach this container. 
What is the best solution to limit users to only attach container which they start?

I confused between some root access, namespaces, etc. which I don't know as well as Docker.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to say 'create new groups for each user' but then you would have to configure each group with Docker permissions which would end you up back where you are. Doing a bit of research it is also not possible for groups to be part of groups. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47645/group-within-group-file-permissions

I do not believe there is a manageable way to accomplish what you are wanting to do short of putting each user into there own machine/instance/vm.

If you figure this out I would be interested in knowing the solution. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

**Anyone who can run any Docker command has unlimited root access over the host.**

Docker doesn’t have any built-in way to restrict access in the way you’re suggesting.  Anyone can `docker attach` to anyone else’s containers; anyone can `docker stop; docker rm` them; anyone can `docker run` a seemingly identical container but with different volume mounts; anyone can `docker run -v/:/host ...` and make arbitrary changes to the host filesystem as root.

You should reconsider whether you can use Docker at all on a multi-user system like this.  Adding someone to the `docker` group is equivalent to giving them unrestricted `sudo` access (and it is a trivial `docker run` command for them to give it to themselves if they don’t already have it).

Comment: Additionally: Installation does require root, usage no longer does. "If you would like to use Docker as a non-root user, you should now consider adding your user to the “docker” group with something like:  sudo usermod -aG docker your-user" - https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ . While container PID processes doe run as root inside the container and there for can 'break out' to the host; for most use cases adding a user to the docker group is preferred over adding the user to the 'sudo' group of the host.

Comment: If you can edit the host's `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/sudoers` files, you're root, full stop.  And if you can run any Docker command, you can `docker run --rm -it -v/:/host busybox vi /host/etc/sudoers`.  Technically your uid isn't 0 and you're not running `sudo`...but practically speaking, you're root.

Comment: Yes, you are right. To handle this situation I wrote a script and users can only run my custom commands. However, the problem is still there. I wonder if there is a way that I create a container with passwords or something like that?
@DavidMaze

Answer (score 1):

It's quite the rabbit hole to do, but in theory, you can run docker daemons inside docker containers.

So you have the master docker daemon running on the host.  For each client you wish to isolate, you create a docker container that:

1. Runs a docker daemon
2. Runs an ssh daemon (for access by client)
3. Accepts the client's credentials
4. Is mapped to a different set of ports on the host
5. Is mapped to a different section of disk

So client A ssh's to your host on port A, which is redirected to docker container A's ssh daemon.  Within that container, Client A has a docker Daemon they can work with to download, run, and do anything else with containers... limited to the resources of docker container A.

Client B ssh's to your host on port B, which is redirected to docker container B's ssh daemon.  Within that container, Client B has a docker Daemon they can work with to download, run, and do anything else with containers... limited to the resources of docker container B.

If client A or client B runs a port scan against the host, sure, they'll be able to tell that multiple ssh servers are up and running.  But without the other's credentials, they can't get in.

Any holes in this?

Answer (score 0):

The docker permission is a pain in the ass. Any docker user has root access, too crazy!

No way out? Maybe use a less danger way (well, still a danger way):

1. Only put admin in docker group
2. Set up ssh in container, and get IP address
3. Other users access container by ssh

So damage is likely limited in container, and your host system seems safer.